# Plot VectorPlot and Plot in the same figure

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot both P1 and P2 in the same figure. What to do?

```
range = 2;
P1 = VectorPlot[{x^2 - x, y^2 - y}, {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, 
   range},VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorStyle -> Black]
P2 = Plot[1 - x, {x, -2, 2}]
Show[P1,P2]
```

Q1: I get three plots, P1, P2 and their combination plot (attached here). I only want to get the combined plot, not P1, P2. How to do that?

Q2: The vector fields are normalized, all vectors have the same length. How to make them to their original size?

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're asking.  Your code *does* plot `P1` and `P2` in the same figure—but you seem to think it doesn't.  If the results are not what you want, what do you want to be done differently?

Comment: Also, to make the arrows in `P1` black, add `VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorStyle -> Black` to the options.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I get two different pots. I want to combine them in a single plot.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It is done. Thank you. But the vector fields are normalized, all vahe the same length. How to make them to their original size?

Comment: When I run your code I get three plots:  one showing `P1`, one showing `P2`, and one showing `P1` and `P2` combined.  The last of these is what I assume you want.  Do you get something different?  If so, can you [edit] your question to show what your output is and describe what you want to change?

Comment: I get three plots. Yes you are right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146625/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-user1942348).

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close because the solution is to add semicolons at the end of each line... a very basic fact that is frequently stated and displayed in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to display `P1` and `P2`, put a semicolon after the lines in which you set them.  This effectively suppresses the output, but still stores the plots in the appropriate variables.

To scale the arrows proportional to the magnitude of the vector field, use `VectorScaling -> Automatic`.